# iOS Javascript resource path of file within WebView?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, uiwebview, webview

so I'm trying to figure out what the path would be to load a javascript file into a webview .html document?

Basically, I am trying to do this through webview's stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString method, and passing in javascript that appends a script element to the current page, and this script loads in a file from the device's app bundle.

What I've tried so far is:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"s=document.createElement('script');s.src='%@';document.body.appendChild(s);", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/file.js", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]]];
```

I know the webview's method of appending javascript works as I can load in scripts without issue through an http:// path, I just am having difficulty getting the correct path for my file.js that is within my application's resources.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString* path = [bundle bundlePath];
```

This gives you the path to your bundle. From there on, you can navigate your folder structure.